# template is not working magento 2 admin customer_index_edit

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, xml

I am calling a js function form this file current.phtml like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ $(document).ready(function($) {
   updateAjax();
    }); });
</script>
```

And this is my function here in `js.phtml` same module same directory

```
<script>
function updateAjax(current,returnpaymentid)
    {
        console.log(asdada);
        resetPaymentBlock();
    }
</script>
```

Here is my `customer_edit_index.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
       <referenceBlock name="customer_form">
         <block class="TM\CreditManagement\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\CurrentTransactions" name="tm_cm_current" >
        </block>

         <block class="TM\CreditManagement\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\ArchivedTransactions" name="tm_cm_archived" >
          <action method="setTabLabel">
              <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Archived Transactions</argument>
          </action>
        </block>
        <block class="TM\CreditManagement\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Statements" name="tm_cm_statements" >
          <action method="setTabLabel">
              <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Statements</argument>
          </action>
        </block>
        <block class="TM\CreditManagement\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\PaymentsReceived" name="tm_cm_received" >
          <action method="setTabLabel">
              <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Payments Received</argument>
          </action>
        </block>



      </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class="TM\CreditManagement\Block\Adminhtml\Transactions\Current" template="TM_CreditManagement::transactions/js.phtml" name="before_js_cm"/>
        </referenceContainer>

</body>
```

All other are working fine except the last one with template "transactions/js.phtml" this templete is not loading